# Create New Tab With its own FXML

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I have a TabPane that is declared via FXML.  I am trying to add new tabs dynamically.

I have created a separate class for those tabs:

```
public class DetailTab extends Tab {
```

My Controller.java is generating new DetailTabs and adding them to my TabPane:

```
detailsPane.getTabs().add(new DetailTab(title));
```

Within the DetailTab.java, I am trying to populate the new tab's contents with a different FXML file, depending on the String passed to the DetailTab constructor.

```
try {
                System.out.println("Trying fxml");
                this.setContent(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("tabUserComments.fxml")));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This creates a NullPointerException.  The tabUserComments.fxml file IS in the project's root directory along with DetailTab.java.

[IntelliJ project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN33v.jpg)

What is the best way to do this? CAN I even set the contents to an FXML file from within the DetailTab itself? I'd like to avoid using the Controller to set the contents of the tab, if possible.

Comment: you seem to want partial view, I don't think javafx support that , besides when you load different fxml files with same backing controller, new instances of the controller will be created, they won't share the same instance/state

Comment: I am happy to create a separate controller for each individual tab's fxml, if necessary.  I did notice the exception clears if I assign a different controller to the tabUserComments.fxml.

However, now I am seeing that the tab is still not populated by the new fxml data.

Comment: So is there a better way to populate a tab with a separate fxml file?  I plan on having a lot of tabs and would prefer to design them separately, as opposed to bloating my DetailTab class with all the different code for each one.

Comment: not exactly related but you can see how [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209789/javafx-tabpane-tab-how-to-add-content-which-fills-the-tab-in-size)

Comment: Have a look at the [Custom components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) section of the Introduction to FXML Document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a partial solution by using the following code within my DetailsTab.java class:

```
try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("tabUserComments.fxml"));
                loader.setController(this);
                this.setContent(loader.load());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This is still causing issues as I cannot access the data contained in the controls of the tabUserComments.fxml.  I will mark this as answered, however, as the passing of data is another question entirely; this does allow designing each tab with individual FXML files.

Comment: `loader.setController(this);` messing controls and controllers is a bad smell imho